# How to Use Virtual Mode for large data in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am posting to see if there is a way to improve some legacy code. The code will populate a DataGridView with x amount of rows. Initially, the code worked fine as the populating data was of a small quantity. However, there has been an extreme increase in data and I am finding that the performance in populating the DataGridView to be very slow.

Basically, I know there are several considerations (Virtual Mode, for instance). However, the approach that I want to take is using an array or List (and then convert it to an array) and add the range of the row by calling Rows.AddRange(array). However, I am having trouble implementing it.

As it stands, this is what code exists:

```
if (value !=0)
{
 int row = 0;
 dataGridView1.AddRow();
 dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0] = "Test";
 dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[1] = 9;
 dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[2] = "Test Two";
 dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[3] = "Test Three";
 row++;
}

if (valueTwo !=0)
{
 dataGridView1.AddRow();
 dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0] = "Test";
 dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[1] = 9;
 dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[2] = "Test Two";
 dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[3] = "Test Three";
 row++;
}
```

So, this is not efficient at all, of course. I know .AddRow() is a taxing method in itself and individually adding rows, one-by-one is not great.

I have tried something like:

```
object[] data = {"Test", 9, "Test Two", "Test Three"};
List<DataGridViewRow> list = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
  DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
  row.SetValues(data[i]);
  list.Add(row);
 }
 dataGridViewRow1.Rows.AddRange(list.ToArray());
```

However, doing this gets me a NullPointerException on the SetValues line.

I understand that the best way of doing this is either make a DataTable or use Virtual Mode but I want to try out using this method of adding the range and passing in a container for the data, rather than adding a row.

I hope I am clear with my explanation. Let me know if I need to further explain.

EDIT: I think using Virtual Mode is the best way to go. I am not sure how to really do it, though. I checked MSN's tutorial but I was slightly confused by it. If I were to implement Virtual Mode for 100,000 rows, how would I go about doing it. Nothing really fancy, just displaying a total of 10,000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

i can prefer DataTable is the correct approach,
but still if you want to add data to your gridView dynamically,
first you need to add columns then rows.

```
private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var lstTemp = new List<test>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                lstTemp.Add(new test() { Name = "Test", No = i, Desc = "Desc " + i, Desc1 = "Desc1 " + i });

            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Name", "Name");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("No", "Number");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Desc", "Description1");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Desc1", "Description2");

            foreach (var temp in lstTemp)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow) dataGridView1.Rows[0].Clone();
                row.Cells[0].Value = temp.Name;
                row.Cells[1].Value = temp.No;
                row.Cells[2].Value = temp.Desc;
                row.Cells[3].Value = temp.Desc1;
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }

        public class test
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int No { get; set; }
            public string Desc { get; set; }
            public string Desc1 { get; set; }
        }
```

this might help you,

Answer (score 0):

for your case you need to add columns before rows,

```
object[] data = { "Test", 9, "Test Two", "Test Three" };

            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Name", "Name");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("No", "Number");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Desc", "Description1");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Desc1", "Description2");

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a BindingList that you populate with your data, you can have a class to map the propreties or use a dynamic one. You have to frist create the cols so you can Bind de data: here´s one example:

```
        DataGridViewCell cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colFileName = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        {
            CellTemplate = cell,
            Name = "Value1",
            HeaderText = "Value 1",
            DataPropertyName = "Col1" 
        };

        DataGridViewCell cell2 = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colFileName2 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        {
            CellTemplate = cell2,
            Name = "Value2",
            HeaderText = "Value 2",
            DataPropertyName = "Col2" 
        };
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(colFileName);
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(colFileName2);

        List<DataPopulate> list = new List<DataPopulate>();
        list.Add(new DataPopulate() { Col1 = "tes1", Col2 = "teste2"});
        list.Add(new DataPopulate() { Col1 = "tes1", Col2 = "teste2" });
        list.Add(new DataPopulate() { Col1 = "tes1", Col2 = "teste2" });

        var dataPopulateList = new BindingList<DataPopulate>(list); 

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataPopulateList;
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. Is this the fastest way to populate, given my posted original code?

Comment: Also, if I were to do a simple Virtual Mode to display 50 rows at a time, what would I need to do ?